# AWS Fargate Cluster Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

It's unclear to me exactly how the underlying AWS Fargate cluster works under the covers.

Does the underlying cluster still scale up and down as needed when the tasks need more instances, and if so, where is that specified?

Comment: I don't think you'd find documentation regarding that. The whole point is that you don't have to worry about it. It's like Lambda where you just get the resources you use and you don't have to worry where they come from.

Comment: @kichik that's not true. With Fargate, you still need to take care of scaling for number of containers. Fargate takes care of scaling/managing the cluster. "AWS Fargate makes it easy to scale your applications."

Answer (score 10):

Yes, Application Autoscaling works fine with Fargate.

Using CloudFormation:

- create an `AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget` and specify for `RescoureId` your `service/<cluster-name>/<service-name>`
- create your `AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy` and specify **only** the `ScalingTargetId` (do not declare  `ScalableDimension`, `ServiceNamespace` and `RescoureId`)

Add it will scale in/out your ECS service

Comment: Is this correct? As in, are you attempting to answer a different question from what the OP asked? AFAIK, Fargate does not need to be bothered with any configuration related to "how to scale".

Comment: yes, Fargate hides the EC2 instances; regarding the autoscaling you have to configure it using the Appliccation autoscaling. Fargate will automagiccally provide more host accordingly to the number of contsiners set by you, or by tge autlolscaling configuratilon

Comment: what about autoscaling up/down fargate tasks in a service with sqs depth ?

Comment: @Zangetsu you can use any metrics/alarm to trigger an autoscaling event

Comment: Does fargate allow your cluster to scale down to 0 machines if no requests are coming in?

Comment: @chrismarx as far as the `AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget` has `MinCapacity` set at 0, it will scale down to 0